# Retorno de Requisição - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Iniciei os estudos com angular4, e estou tentando obter o retorno `json` de uma requisição simples através de um `service`.

Porém ao chamar o método que faz a requisição, o mesmo me apresenta o seguinte erro no meu componente `login.component.ts`:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => void'.

Entretanto, ao executar esse mesmo método dentro do meu `component` ele funciona normal e me retorna o meu `json`

Abaixo segue os código do meu `service` e do meu `component`:

---

**credentials.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CredentialsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getCredentials(){
    var url = 'http://luingry.com.br/easyjob/WebServices/angular/login.php';

    this.http.get(url)
    .map(dados =>{ return dados.json();});
  }

}
```

---

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//importando o serviço
import { CredentialsService } from './services/credentials.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public c: CredentialsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.c.getCredentials.subscribe(g =>{
      console.log(g);
    });
  }

}
```

O que fazer para obter o `json` da minha requisição através do `service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só faltou o return no http do serviço (por isso o typescript interpreta que você retorna um observable sem valor):

```
public getCredentials(){
    var url = 'http://luingry.com.br/easyjob/WebServices/angular/login.php';
    /* return aqui */
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map(dados =>{ return dados.json();});
  }
```

Comment: Nossa cara, que bobeira minha... Vi que era problema com return mas nem me liguei que a minha função não tava retornando nada.

Comment: Talvez o que tenha te confundido seja o return do map... Eu costumo deixar sem return a arrow function de um comando só... .map(dados => dados.json());

Comment: Entendi... Mas então eu coloquei um `console.log()` fora do `subscribe` e o mesmo apresenta o resultado `undefined`, só que quando coloco o `console.log` dentro do `subscribe` o mesmo me apresenta o `json`... Sabe o pq disso? Quer q eu abra outra perguntar para poder me ajudar?

Comment: Não sei se entendi certo sua pergunta... Isso acontece pq a chamada é assíncrona... O subscribe só assina o evento http passando uma função no parâmetro e essa função só é executada no momento que o resultado do http volta... Colocando fora do subscribe você irá pedir a variável g que nem existe not contexto de fora, por isso volta undefined

Comment: No caso então tenho que fazer validação de usuário e senha dentro do `subscribe`? Ou existe algum meio mais correto?

Comment: No caso de autenticação o certo é fazer toda validação de segurança do lado do servidor, pois o front é totalmente manipulável pelo cliente. O site deve estar servido com https e ter um serviço de autenticação que recebe o usuário e senha postado dentro do corpo do post. Após enviar o usuário e senha neste canal seguro, o servidor deve fornecer um token de acesso gerado randomicamente e armazenar em algum recurso para relacionar o usuário ao token gerado. No client dentro do subscribe armazenar o token e postar em todo request. O check do token deve ser no servidor obrigando login se expirar.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post que explica um fluxo de autenticação jwt legal com server PHP. Só cuidado com o post de senha na URL, não faça isso... Coloque no corpo da mensagem pra ir criptografado no https: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171466/5108174